# Set Margins In Excel Using Excel Interop VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel

Anyone have code to set margins(top,left,right,bottom) using excel interop and vb.net. I think it must be part of the worksheet object but maybe the workbook object. Having a tough time finding an example. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it its part of the worksheet object...

i.e.

xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.TopMargin=0.5

Comment: I know this is an old topic, but in case this won't affect the output excel file try "20" instead of "0.5". 

Somehow the same app works on one machine fine but on the other doesn't. My guess is that Excel versions and/or localization settings has an effect on it. One bases its unit as "pixel", one as "millimeter" or "centimeter", thus "0.5" has almost no effect on the margin.

Answer (score 1):

Margins are set through the [PageSetup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pagesetup_members.aspx) object which you get from on the [WorkSheet.PageSetup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.pagesetup%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) property.

Comment: Charles thats what I thought, but excel isnt taking it for some reason. My margins are not getting set in the output file

Comment: Don't know what your problem might be. I'm actually using SpreadSheetGear which wraps the Excel object model, so I don't use Excel classes directly. Maybe if you post the non-working code, someone will notice the problem.

Comment: ws.PageSetup.Orentation=Excel.xlpageorentation.xlLandscape
ws.PageSetup.Zoom=False
ws.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide=1
ws.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall=1
ws.PageSetup.TopMargin=0.5
ws.PageSetup.LeftMargin=0.25
ws.PageSetup.RightMargin=0.25
ws.PageSetup.BottomMargin=0
ws.Protect()

Disregard any typos I may have made. Everything is setting fine, but the margins

Answer (score 0):

Margin values have to mentioned in points. Use InchesToPoints(Double) or CentimetersToPoints(Double) to specify the value.

```
Eg: 

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application _ExcelAppl = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook _ExcelWorkBook = oXL.Workbooks.Add(missing);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet _ExcelWorkSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;
_ExcelWorkSheet.PageSetup.TopMargin = _ExcelAppl.InchesToPoints(0.25);
```