# C# Excel Print Margins

Tags: c#, excel, margins

I want to adjust the print settings of my Excel file which I generate with a program I made in C#. I want the setting to be: 'Page suitable(or fit) for 1 page'.
(In dutch it is Blad passend maken voor 1 pagina) :p
This you can choose this option at: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUSXE.jpg).

I know margins are set through the `PageSetup` object but I just can't find how to do this.

Please help me out here :)

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602408/set-margins-in-excel-using-excel-interop-vb-net)

Answer (score 2):

This may help?

```
osheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$5:$G$" & curLine + 1
osheet.PageSetup.PrintTitleColumns = "$A:$A"
osheet.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = "$1:$4"
osheet.PageSetup.Orientation = XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape
osheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "SomeText"
obook.CustomViews.Add("Print Top Left", True, True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could manipulate the Excel settings by using [Office Primary Interop Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx)

More specifically, [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms280798%28v=office.11%29.aspx) tells you how to manipulate the Page Setup using Excel Interop (part of Office PIA)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sheet.PageSetup.TopMargin = 1;
sheet.PageSetup.BottomMargin = 1;
sheet.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 1;
sheet.PageSetup.RightMargin = 1;
```